# Applying shifts in SQL

Tags: sql

Apologies if that is difficult to understand, I work for a survey company and am relatively new to SQL.

I have the following two tables:

**targetReadings**

```
id Epoch PointNumber Easting Northing
```

**targetShift**

```
ID Epoch PointNumber ShiftEasting ShiftNorthing
```

We have data automatically going in to **targetReadings**. We then plot this on graphs to view on our website. Sometimes we need to apply shifts to our data. I need a query that will run through the data and apply the correct shift value. For example, if I have a point called `R101` that has coordinates `East 100, North 500`. This may get knocked and the latest reading maybe `East 101, North 501`. I would then put an entry in **targetShift**:

```
 2015-01-01, R101, -1, -1
```

Then a week later it may get knocked again and give me readings of `East 105, North 105`. I would then put another entry in **targetShift**:

```
2015-01-08, R101, -4, -4
```

I need a query that will run through the data in **targetReadings** and apply the correct shift based on the data from **targetShift**.

My current query is

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a.Epoch > r.Epoch 
    THEN a.Easting + r.ShiftEasting
    END as ShiftEast
    , a.PointNumber
    , a.Epoch
    , r.Epoch
FROM
    TargetReadings a
    inner join targetShift r on r.PointNumber = a.PointNumber
```

This works but it brings back a result for every entry in **targetShift**, as this is a large project there could be many shifts for each point. I only want 1 result for each entry in **targetReadings**.

Thank you for your help.

Here is some example data, I have the data for both tables and a table below of the results I want from the query:

**TargetShift**

```
PointNumber Epoch               ShiftEasting    ShiftNorthing
CB501       01/01/2014 00:00    0               0
CB501       01/01/2015 00:00    100000          100000
CB501       02/01/2015 00:00    200000          200000
```

**TargetReadings**

```
PointNumber Epoch               Easting     Northing
CB501       31/12/2014 00:01    528196.679  178392.171
CB501       31/12/2014 01:01    528196.679  178392.170
CB501       01/01/2015 00:01    528196.675  178392.165
CB501       01/01/2015 01:01    528196.676  178392.166
CB501       02/01/2015 00:01    528196.679  178392.167
CB501       02/01/2015 05:01    528196.679  178392.167
```

**Expected Query Result**

```
PointNumber Epoch               ShiftEasting    ShiftNorthing
CB501       31/12/2014 00:01    528196.679      178392.171
CB501       31/12/2014 01:01    528196.679      178392.170
CB501       01/01/2015 00:01    628196.675      278392.165
CB501       01/01/2015 01:01    628196.676      278392.166
CB501       02/01/2015 00:01    728196.679      378392.167
CB501       02/01/2015 05:01    728196.679      378392.167
```

Comment: It would be enough to have a few (5 - 10) most interesting values for `TargetReadings`. Most importantly, provide **expected result**, what you want to get, not the wrong result that you are getting now. Including incorrect result is OK, but it is not useful, unless you can point out what is wrong and what would be the correct output.

Comment: The results I have listed are the correct results, I calculated them manually. I have removed most of the unnecessary entries.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It was not clear. Maybe add these words "expected query result". Are you sure that there is no typo? Do you have 3 rows in `TargetShift`? The names of columns are the same for both provided `TargetShift` and `TargetReadings`, which is confusing. Also, you should use formatting when posting such tables. There is a button "code sample" on the toolbar above the question text. Use it. And you can see the preview of the question how it would look like after the edit just below it.

Comment: Wonderful. We are getting there. One more question: How would expected result change if we add these **two** rows to the `TargetShift`: `CB501       01/01/2015 00:30    100000          100000` and `CB501       01/01/2015 00:40    100000          100000`

Comment: There would be no change to the results as the shift value has not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining sample data and your clarifications in comments it looks like you don't want to sum **all** shifts, but you want to add only the most recent shift, if any. In this case `OUTER APPLY` seems the best choice.

**sample data:**

```
DECLARE @TargetShift TABLE (PointNumber char(5), Epoch datetime, ShiftEasting float, ShiftNorthing float);
INSERT INTO @TargetShift (PointNumber, Epoch, ShiftEasting, ShiftNorthing) VALUES 
('CB501', '2014-01-01T00:00:00', 0     , 0     ),
('CB501', '2015-01-01T00:00:00', 100000, 100000),
('CB501', '2015-01-02T00:00:00', 200000, 200000);

DECLARE @TargetReadings TABLE (PointNumber char(5), Epoch datetime, Easting float, Northing float);
INSERT INTO @TargetReadings (PointNumber, Epoch, Easting, Northing) VALUES
('CB501', '2014-12-31T00:01:00', 528196.679, 178392.171),
('CB501', '2014-12-31T01:01:00', 528196.679, 178392.170),
('CB501', '2015-01-01T00:01:00', 528196.675, 178392.165),
('CB501', '2015-01-01T01:01:00', 528196.676, 178392.166),
('CB501', '2015-01-02T00:01:00', 528196.679, 178392.167),
('CB501', '2015-01-02T05:01:00', 528196.679, 178392.167);
```

**query**

```
SELECT
    R.PointNumber
    , R.Epoch
    , R.Easting + ISNULL(OA_Shift.ShiftEasting, 0) as ShiftEast
    , R.Northing + ISNULL(OA_Shift.ShiftNorthing, 0) as ShiftNorth
FROM
    @TargetReadings AS R
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            S.ShiftEasting
            , S.ShiftNorthing
        FROM @TargetShift AS S
        WHERE
            S.PointNumber = R.PointNumber
            AND S.Epoch < R.Epoch
        ORDER BY S.Epoch DESC
    ) OA_Shift
ORDER BY
    R.PointNumber
    , R.Epoch
;
```

**result**

```
PointNumber    Epoch                      ShiftEast     ShiftNorth
CB501          2014-12-31 00:01:00.000    528196.679    178392.171
CB501          2014-12-31 01:01:00.000    528196.679    178392.17
CB501          2015-01-01 00:01:00.000    628196.675    278392.165
CB501          2015-01-01 01:01:00.000    628196.676    278392.166
CB501          2015-01-02 00:01:00.000    728196.679    378392.167
CB501          2015-01-02 05:01:00.000    728196.679    378392.167
```

For each row in `TargetReadings` `OUTER APPLY` finds 1 row from `TargetShift` with the same `PointNumber` and dated prior to the row from `TargetReadings`.

If you add an index to `TargetShift` on `(PointNumber, Epoch DESC)` the query should be efficient.

Comment: I've updated the answer, but your comment contradicts what you wrote in the question (or I can't understand it properly). Please add sample data and expected result to your question, then it would be possible to write correct query.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! Saved me a lot of time and effort, thanks again! Just out of interest, if I did want to sum shifts instead, what would the query be? I have both options but maybe the sum of the shifts would be better.

Comment: @mattkb, you are welcome. Now you've seen how you can ask a question in such a way that you'll get good answers. The phrase "I want to sum the shifts" is too vague. Sum all of them for the same point? limited by some range of dates? something else? If you ask another question with the same level of details explaining the logic, a good representative sample data, expected result and clean formatting, most likely you would get a good answer. In the end another query may be quite different to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS APLLY` in this situation:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN a.Epoch > r.Epoch
THEN a.Easting + r.ShiftEasting
END as ShiftEast, a.PointNumber, a.Epoch, r.Epoch
FROM TargetReadings a
cross apply( select top 1 ts.* from targetShift ts where ts.PointNumber = a.PointNumber order by ID desc) r
```

Comment: I get this error when I use that: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "a.PointNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: Does TargetReadings table contains PointNumber column?? I've copy pasted your query

Comment: Yes it does, the design of the tables are listed in my question above. The original query I used worked, the one you have given me does not.

Comment: Does this work? `select PointNumber FROM TargetReadings`
Sorry I had cross join instead of cross apply. Check now

Comment: It not working because of error? Is error `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 The multi-part identifier "a.PointNumber" could not be bound` correced?

Comment: No, the query runs but the results are not correct, it only brings back a result for the readings after the last shift, I need a result for every entry in the targetreadings table.

Comment: That statement will give you every row in Readings with last of its corresponding in shifts. Provide us with some test data and desired result set from that data.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,it just indicate,

```
 SELECT CASE 
        WHEN a.Epoch > r.Epoch
            THEN a.Easting + r.ShiftEasting
        END AS ShiftEast
    ,a.PointNumber
    ,a.Epoch
    ,r.Epoch
FROM TargetReadings a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY PointNumber ORDER BY [datecolumn] DESC
            ) rn
    FROM targetshift
    ) r ON r.PointNumber = a.PointNumber
WHERE r.rn = 1
```

Comment: I get this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Comment: This does not work: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'datecolumn'. If I change this to epoch, then the results are not correct.

Comment: yes 'datecolumn' was just fake column.you hv to use that column in place which would do sorintg.did you try running only inner select to view result that it return.I was just trying to show you a way.not giving exact query.

Comment: I have tried this and the results are still not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Mat, looks to me you need the entry in targetShift for each pointNumber with max(epoch), i.e. the newest entry. One way to achieve this is to add a condition to filter to targetShift table, like:

```css
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a.Epoch > r.Epoch 
    THEN a.Easting + r.ShiftEasting
    END as ShiftEast
    , a.PointNumber
    , a.Epoch
    , r.Epoch
FROM
    TargetReadings a
    inner join targetShift r on r.PointNumber = a.PointNumber    
WHERE 
    r.epoch= (SELECT max(epoch) 
              FROM   targetShift r1 
              WHERE  r.Pointnumber=  r1.Pointnumber)
```

Another point: intentionally or not, your query will only return TargetReadings that have one or more entries in targetShift - maybe not what is required.